# Qt/C++ physics engine similar to iOS UIKit Dynamics

Tags: c++, qt, qtquick2, physics-engine, uikit-dynamics

I was wondering if there are any tools for simulating physical movement for animations in `Qt`. I remember I once saw on `iOS` that one could drag a panel down faster and the panel would bounce on the bottom of the screen with an intensity proportionally with the force it was dragged with; i believe it's called [UIKit Dynamics](http://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/ae629fee90392573a33a1e215c9dc935.gif). Something like this:

[image]

Or let's say I wish to create this type of bouncing effect for my UI:

[image]

Here the progress circle elapsed value is slightly bouncing after reaching its new value. These effects can't be done just with easing curves Qt animations offer.

Does anyone know if there are ways to create these types of animations with `Qt Widgets` or `Qt Quick`? Is there something there which could be integrated with `Qt Animations`?

Comment: I'm waffling on this a bit, but tending toward a close vote (asking for tutorial/library). http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ may be a better fit for this question.

Comment: @user4581301 Didn't know about that StackExchange site. I'll move the question there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every animation api has it, and it is not a "physics engine", it is called "easing curves". They are commonly used to imitate physical interaction and spice up otherwise boring and lifeless animation. Naturally, [Qt has them too](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qeasingcurve.html), there is a wide array of the most frequently used ones, and you can make your own too.

> These effects can't be done just with easing curves Qt animations
>   offer.

It doesn't seem you even tried. All of the effect examples you posted can be achieved using easing curves. For example, the easing curve for the second effect would have to be something like this:

[image]

Ramping up almost linearly, until overshooting the target, holding for a moment after which easing back to the target.

Also, if you plan on doing fancy animated UIs, I'd suggest to use QML instead, and stay away from the `QtWidget` stack - QML is tremendously faster and easier to do modern UI with. The widgets aren't suited for it, you could to it, but it will be a tedious process.

Comment: I tried but didn't know you can also create custom easing curves. Thanks!

Comment: @JacobKrieg - this part "intensity proportionally with the force it was dragged with" you will have to do some extra coding for. And it would not be the force, since device input rarely has a notion of its force, but its velocity. You will have to keep track of the velocity if you want proportional reaction.